# Validating url in POST parameters in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to validate that the parameters in the POST request sent are valid URLs.

This is my views.py

```
views.py
def post(self, request):
    if url_validator(request) == 400:
        return Jsonresponse(status=400)
```

This is my utils.py. This file will contain all general methods and classes.

```
def url_validator(request, ext):
        for key, value in request.data.items():
        value = request.data[key]
        try:
            URLValidator(value)
        except ValidationError:
            return 400
```

When I call the function `url_validator` from views, it executes but doesn't return the exception when either of the request parameters doesn't contain URLs. 
For example, if I pass a parameter `param1: "some string"`, it doesn't go through the ValidationError path.
How do I go about getting the correct return from the function?

Comment: Are you using Django Rest Framework? Then, serializers are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A validator class doesn't take the input to be validated in its instantiation, it takes it when you call the instantiated object:

```
validator = URLValidator()
validator(value)
```

But this really isn't how to do validation in Django. Either use a form, or if you're processing submitted JSON, use a django-rest-framework serializer.